# Need a way to allow users to login on Windows 7 only if their credentials are valid on an external server

Tags: windows-7, windows-authentication, remote-server

I need to develop a solution that allows users to login on windows 7 only if windows 7 has access to Internet and the user credentials are valid when probed against an external server. Do you guys know any script/solution to do that?

The intention is to develop a way to restrict access to a given windows 7 machine if users were banned from the external server.

Regards, Hugo

Answer (score 1):

You will need to consult [Windows 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138) for this.